# wkwebview cannot load http image

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I am using wkwebview to load a https url, it successed. But cannot load the image in the web page, the image url is starting with "http".I have set transpost security in info.plist like below, but it still not works.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Did you add your whitelisted urls?

Comment: @ReinierMelian no, how to add?

Answer (score 0):

Add your url domain here, in info plist

[image]

Comment: @zhouxinle can you post the error you are receiving in console?